# INSTEAD OF (Deleted table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, servidor, tsql

Estou com problemas para criar esta trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGmonitoraClientes ON TB_CLIENTES INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE TB_CLIENTES SET clienteAtivo = 0 FROM TB_CLIENTES WHERE CODcliente = deleted.CODcliente

        INSERT INTO LogClientes VALUES (deleted)

END
```

*Mensagem 4104, Nível 16, Estado 1, Procedimento TGmonitoraClientes, Linha 84
O identificador de várias partes "deleted.CODcliente" não pôde ser associado.*

Não estou conseguindo utilizar a tabela deleted, alguma idéia?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Um procedimento *trigger* pode ser acionado mesmo que não tenha ocorrido qualquer modificação (no caso, apagamento de linha). Por isso é recomendado que, no início do código, seja verificada a quantidade de linhas nas tabelas virtuais INSERTED (e/ou DELETED). No caso desse procedimento, pode-se ter

```
IF (SELECT Count(*) from (SELECT top (1) * from DELETED) as D) = 0
  return;
```

Na instrução UPDATE faltou relacionar as tabelas TB_CLIENTES e DELETED; esse foi o motivo do erro. A cláusula WHERE, nesse caso, não é necessária.

Eis sugestão do código:

```
-- código #1
CREATE TRIGGER TGmonitoraClientes ON TB_CLIENTES 
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN

IF (SELECT Count(*) from (SELECT top (1) * from DELETED) as D) = 0
  return;

UPDATE C
  set clienteAtivo= 0 
  from TB_CLIENTES as C
       inner join DELETED as D on C.CODcliente = D.CODcliente;

INSERT INTO LogClientes (...)
   SELECT ... from DELETED;

END;
```

A última parte, do INSERT, precisa ser detalhada com a especificação das colunas. 
Falta acrescentar tratamento de erro no código do procedimento *trigger*.

Comment: Estava incompleta a trigger quando postei aqui, realmente ainda tinha uns tratamentos para desenvolver...

Comment: Tudo certo agora, valeu!